# ubuntu automatic stop a daemon doesnt happening

Tags: ubuntu, docker, startup, init

I`m trying to make my mysql server to stop automatically from init.

```
root@server:/# update-rc.d mysql defaults
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/mysql ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
   /etc/rc1.d/K20mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
   /etc/rc6.d/K20mysql -> ../init.d/mysql
```

So the first 3 links in rc0, rc1 and rc6 are for the stopping but it doesnt happening. The host is a docker container with ubuntu 14.04 and init is with PID 1.

Answer (score 0):

For recent and updated versions of Ubuntu, look at the *init* configuration file of mysql

```
/etc/init/mysql.conf
```

these two lines are of interest

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on starting rc RUNLEVEL=[016]
```